# is there any way around HttpOnly cookies?

Tags: google-chrome, login, http, cookies, session

is there any way around HttpOnly cookies ? 
curl
[image]

the headers from network tab

[image]
The response cookies from network tab

[image]
 i have tried sending no SessionID_R3 in the header but didn't work and
 tried to send empty SessionID_R3 but didn't work and finally tried a
 random same length SessionID_R3 but still didn't work !! is there a way i 
can generate these ids myself ?

here is some SessionIDs

if anyone can see a pattern

https://pastebin.com/raw/9gM9MYN5

```
rXsf8YsgKTTNVFCvlB6Wf0oIomaXegUNrcqZx4xvH4KrgmjSVBBx7z6mb624K9uyoo65l48KqOmLdFkljRavW7bVw1XdQxHh9kkLXupkL6hcWnNM3R8nPqjGCWLaI8GU
Kax7v0ZbJEOVTIQpmJcXR8WiUclYJd24kDcMrlk4ptJhT1LnrR1HKx63BujfJeHFQvFqXQNRqxCN1nEbWmHUQZXDrFE2RP64h3kiQ4iETCA0iQVeYxClNz8LWg9NAMAr
UbKIhLK9Moa3TAcNvqLtL84WqA7or8YFpoYAyrvYVCVxbowx586ubXFEM4qcKZ01uIPh756cVLzqtASyfUzKzTOInYUft1Tlqsj4lUubTIRPZWAaYDfyJQsmmPflqeCQ
GsScuVNrowZ8jQIRoTtm69Pq9SuuFh71cI9DZEv9pHQLiVzwf1yn3QmTTSFSL4NMB0A5cmSwXq7tsBxOU0u7by7pNOSe2ujNyciyTzkkeeQJpiA62QYUdkamN2ioATfK
FazV7yHxU3cszPI8YuCjJvCbm2ObhNNVaMLI9ePQzPmLEdDudg0BHW1lFXSbHRfEabXEaeSgW8jXIG4p2E2ntN52m3TbuDiX9Ku1wlQSvAoezb7C9QWPowXTqn16gftk
tWRYlzaeblz0eroMMlhMKihpQ9MZ4plQbh4Bf6aPEMorEBqFA3QBVRjwRHOygGHMpGkOyAoSuZt8myTg1OiqSWn05POj1K8yvyfOgbaKqxr15ZS1Ly9H5XokxEqgpnQJ
HeHMgwdWJuSZo3d7tSrXXgNTZcsqfVYRD5Gx9dqPU02UqPEiSzlS97wKIoH3mc8g4I9QUjWE6B5Y7LUH2tQNcA5Mhw0zksOkZM4ULewAUIPwZLS31fL9iUueBJU1QIVq
7sdsPPel47kSuxSnuQgzbUCVrLcE1dZM0b9mEoJfoLEe44E1TqYFQEvh2i2HnJSx8EAjuNC3h5PUeRR9z2l2iZvRxkrhcNmmY9Oa64UY95DtTu15FQH25wqNk5qdLmb0
kd3coEgEjutjs4GgMlYSI15uR8jmtKqxeDpdb9kxMB9jIpzAe0hCQJHGTMiPcAHmwKolU0b05Qidsuce0hFyabl5oDnR3hBFSPonbNRlLvIhE2l3f2pm3LFYiFvMasSP
XVTLX1CXSmpJA14dS5Yp1CZg3HvV9YBHoaNz0OSMezBS1fuYmtamTPAjTEZ6KVj25ATL35Jd1vzVINy1ZbfVlYUaFYsHilV86FXyhsZ9NnwvFf0V3nMLTzHQSV5FiS3c
```

Comment: This seems to be happening inside your local network. What service are you hosting?

Comment: @harrymc an auto login and setting editing router script ...

Comment: I mean what are you running on `http://192.168.1.1`?

Comment: @harrymc a router

Comment: You could use the Chrome Incognito mode or some add-on to block cookies, but that's all you can do if that website insists on returning cookies.

Comment: @harrymc but this would result in a failed login !!

Comment: It only means you will need to re-logon each time.

Comment: @harrymc 
but i need the cookies why would i even do this ?

Comment: Then I don't understand your problem. What do you want with the cookies?

Comment: @harrymc the cookies are required to view the pages after you login .... i need to grab it using ajax but the cookies are http only !

Comment: You may save the cookies in a file and use `curl -b`. For a complete tutorial of how to work with cookies see [link](https://ec.haxx.se/http-cookies.html).

Comment: i know about that .... but i am talking about the browser i want to do that using js

Comment: JavaScript is off-subject for this site, but see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie).

Comment: @harrymc thanks but i don't want to create cookies i just want to grab them from the response cookies of the server !